# Can ajax read files with custom extensions or any alternative?

Tags: ajax

My question is can ajax handle files with custom extensions ? Consider a file with extension **.laj** or **.cst** or anything random. Let's take an example :

file.cst :

```
Hey ! Load Me
```

Javascript :

```
console.log( loadWithAjax("file.cst") );
```

I tested it and it seems not to work. I tested it with **JQuery Ajax**, and ya it not worked. So is there any other way do gain the result i.e load the **.cst** file just by knowing its location not selecting it !!!

Comment: Cannot reproduce, could you provide actual code?